# sqlcipher - how safe is sqlcipher? has it been hacked?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, security, sqlcipher

It encrypts the SQLLite database at page level, ok thats fine, nothing wrong with that!

but what about your source code? its compiled, but even if its compiled someone could decompile it, retrieve your password and decrypt the database?

Comment: If it's in your code, then someone will be able to get it.  It's just a matter of time and effort.  The real question is, is that effort worth it for them?

Comment: @borrrden if the password is in the code, isnt this like you locking your door, and leave the key under the door mat? I would feel ok if it took years to decompile but it doesnt.

Comment: The only thing you can do is obfuscate, and even that just delays things.  If it is ever in memory, then someone can examine the memory with a debugger.  This is not the first time someone has asked this question either, it is a very popular question with no real answer.

Comment: The key material for SQLCipher databases should never be hard coded into an application. At least some of the key material must come directly from the user. SQLCipher is intended to protect user data, not to be used as DRM.

Answer (score 2):

**How safe is SQLCipher?**

According to the [SQLCipher design documentation](http://sqlcipher.net/design/), it is based on secure components (AES, OpenSSL, HMAC_SHA1, PBKDF2,...). If those claims are correct, it sounds good to me.

What is a bit unusual (to me, at least) is that there is a random IV per page. This is somewhat different to the typical file system encryption mode [AES-XTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory#XEX-based_tweaked-codebook_mode_with_ciphertext_stealing_.28XTS.29). The design used by SQLCipher has certain advantages over AES-XTS, for example writing the same data *again* will not result in the same encrypted page. However, possibly there are disadvantages, for example I'm not quite sure if with SQLCipher it is possible to *move* or *copy* pages (copy encrypted pages to another page). It might not be possible, however from the design document I don't see how this is prevented. Such is the risk if a non-standard encryption mode is used :-) But even if this is a problem, it wouldn't allow an attacker to read the data; it would only allow certain types of attacks. Even with AES-XTS certain types of attacks are possible, so I wouldn't be worried too much.

**What about your source code?**

To keep things save, don't store the password in the code. Instead, let the user enter the password, or store it in a key-chain. This is possible for both [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) and [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios) as far as I see, but I don't know the details.

Comment: to address your comment about moving or copying pages, we account for that by including the page number in the per-page MAC. Thus, the MAC for a page includes the IV, encrypted data, and the page number. Attempting to reorder or move pages around in a database would cause the MAC check to fail.

Comment: @StephenLombardo That makes sense, thanks a lot! It looks like the SQLCipher design is sound, and probably slightly "better" than the standardized AES-XTS.